# Combining dataframes and making column containing dataframe names in R

Tags: r

I am trying to combine two dataframes, but make a column containing part of each dataframe name so that I can identify which dataframe each data came from.  The dataframes are

```
Acme_types_number <- structure(list(type = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), number = c(4L, 6L, 54L, 5L, 5L)), .Names = c("type", "number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

and

```
Acme2_types_number <- structure(list(type = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), number = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L)), .Names = c("type", "number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I can combine these into a single dataframe using

```
df <- rbind(Acme_types_number, Acme2_types_number)
```

which gives the following dataframe df:

```
type    number
red         4
blue        6
green       54
yellow      5
red         5
green       4
red         5
blue        6
yellow      5
red         5
```

However, I want to also add a column that contains the first part of each dataframe name (e.g., the part before the underscore), to give:

```
factory   type number
   Acme    red      4
   Acme   blue      6
   Acme  green     54
   Acme yellow      5
   Acme    red      5
  Acme2  green      4
  Acme2    red      5
  Acme2   blue      6
  Acme2 yellow      5
  Acme2    red      5
```

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that:

```
rbind(data.frame(factory = "Acme", Acme_types_number),
      data.frame(factory = "Acme2", Acme2_types_number))
```

Comment: If this suits your needs and is the best answer consider checking it.